# Para dados booleanos, é mais adequado usar um checkbox ou dois radio buttons?

Tags: ux, booleano

Em uma situação em que precisa escolher algo como sim ou não eu penso logo em usar um *checkbox* já que ele serve justamente para indicar um estado de sim ou não. Mas já vi alguns lugares usar um *radio button* com as duas opções de sim ou não para selecionar uma das duas.

Existe alguma razão para fazer isso? Ou seria erro das pessoas sempre que usar um *radio button* para selecionar um estado binário?

[image: Checkbox]

[image: Radio Button]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em UX nunca tem uma resposta definitiva. Tem sempre que falar em estudar a situação, não vou entrar nesses detalhes. Mas existem fatores que pode ajudar decidir.

O espaço ocupado pode ajudar escolher, obviamente um deles é bem menor do que outro. Em alguns casos ocupar mais espaço, para dar destaque, é mais importante.

Geralmente se você quiser iniciar em um estado neutro, mesmo sem poder deixar selecionado como neutro (não é um *tristate*), o *radio button* tende ser mais fácil e em alguns lugares a única possibilidade do mecanismo de UI que está usando. Em qualquer situação a ação não pode ser desfeita, ou seja, depois que escolheu, só pode trocar a escolha, não pode mais voltar ao estado neutro (é possível fazer algo, mas complica muito para todos, e não faz muito sentido, se fizer então é *tristate*).

Lembre-se que não deixando em estado neutro você está fazendo uma escolha para a pessoa que envia sem muita preocupação. Você pode querer isto ou não e é um fator de escolha de qual usar.

Do ponto de vista de intuição, o *radio button* costuma ser uma ação mais explícita em que i usuário faz escolha, ele fica visível sempre, enquanto um *checkbox*, sem resposta e não selecionado parece a mesma coisa. Além disso muita gente não entende bem um *checkbox* neutro, ele pode parecer selecionado.

Se não tiver um motivo muito forte o *checkbox* deveria ser a primeira escolha. Um motivo forte é se você não vai persistir na aplicação como um booleano.

Aí entramos em outra questão que é usar um booleano ou uma enumeração com dois valores possíveis para representar sim ou não. Isso é comum de ter que parar para pensar, e não vou entrar muito no mérito aqui, mas há casos que o sim ou não, não é uma escolha booleana e deve ser mais explícito. Se não usar um tipo de dado booleano, e um estudo já deve ter sido feito para decidir isso, então o *radio button* tende ser a melhor escolhe.

Isso já implica que se você deve escolher entre um modo ou outro (somente dois) que não representam sim/não, o *checkbox* não deveria ser opção, porque uma enumeração deve ser usada.

Mas lembre-se que a UI não precisa obrigatoriamente seguir a forma de uso interno da aplicação. Tudo pode se for bem justificado.

Outro ponto a considerar é o posicionamento da pergunta e da resposta. É comum inverterem a ordem da pergunta e resposta em um *checkbox*, mas isso é outra questão. Fica esquisito e menos intuitivo, especialmente em formulários de entrada de dados.

Não está na pergunta, mas um *dropdown* pode ser uma opção interessante para manter o espaço ocupado pequeno e ser mais explícito, sendo fácil manter em estado neutro e até permitir voltar para o neutro. Em formulários de entidades da aplicação pode ser melhor que o *radio button*, apesar de ser mais difícil de usar com o *mouse*, o que pode ser uma *feature* ou não. Um *radio button* tende ser mais usado para entrada de dados não duradouras e que precisa de uma seleção rápida.

Se estiver usando ou puder usar um dia um *tristate* ou ter opções que não são só sim ou não, então o *radio button* ou *dropdown* devem ser a melhor opção, mesmo que o *checkbox* atenda as expectativas iniciais.

Se tiver muitos campos assim, o *checkbox* se torna muito mais adequado para economizar espaço. Mas espaço não deve ser a primeira análise para escolher.

Answer (score -1):

A experiência de usuário deve ser levada em conta, estética também, mas geralmente checkbox são utilizadas para selecionar um ou mais opções, diferente de radiobutton que é  um ou outro.
Deve-se pensar, o usuário obrigatoriamente tem que escolher ao menos UMA das opções? (radiobutton)
Ou ele vai selecionar diversas opções? (checkbox) Levando em consideração a entrada de dados da resposta, o que vai interferir essas informações OBRIGATORIAMENTE sim ou não (radiobutton) ou diversas opções.
Supondo em um sistema onde você vai perguntar que tipo de benefícios um funcionário quer, você pode deixar diversos benefícios e o usuário seleciona os desejados.
Em um outro exemplo em uma prova de questões de A a E, apenas uma é a correta, logo apenas uma deve ser selcionada (radiobutton).
O ideal é validar pensando em diversos tipos de cenários.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).